# Nohoist in a monorepo with Nextjs and React-native: unable to resolve react

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo, yarnpkg

The project I am working on consists of a monorepo (with yarn) containing a react-native application (expo in particular) and a NestJS server. Today I needed to integrate NestJS with NextJS and came across the error "Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component". This was since both the server (with NextJs) and the mobile application (with React-Native) required the react module, but with different versions.
I solved it by adding the nohosit option to the packages.json file at the root of the monorepo:

```
"nohoist": [
    "**/react", "**/react/**", 
    "**/react-dom", "**/react-dom/**"
  ]
```

However, although this solved the problem with the server (NestJS and NextJS) it created a new one with the react-native application which can't find the react module:

```
Unable to resolve module react from [myDir]\node_modules\@react-native-community\netinfo\src\index.ts: react could not be found within the project.

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
```

I am not currently authorized to share the repository, but of course, if more information is needed I will provide it immediately

Answer (score 0):

For now, I have solved the problem by retracing my steps. That is, I removed react from nohoist and solved the duplicate react module issue by adding the following piece of code in the root package.json:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  }
```

However, I am not convinced that it is the best solution and that it will not give me problems in the future.